# PrimeNg AutoComplete Multiple - Preselect value

Tags: angular, autocomplete, default-value, primeng

[image]

In the PrimeNg AutoComplete Multiple mode, is there a way to display preselect values? I have tried to add `<p-autoComplete value="myValue" ></p-autoComplete>` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so I found a solution for that. Do it with a formControl.

In the html do this `<p-autoComplete [formControl]="myValue" ></p-autoComplete>`, and in the component do this `public myValue= new FormControl([]);` and `this.myValue.setValue(initialValues);`

Comment: how to do it with template-driven form?